# uploadify and paperclip on rails 3.1

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.1, uploadify

i'm trying simply to upload a file using uploadify and paperclip.

This is index view:

```
<%- session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] -%>

$('#upload').uploadify({
    'uploader'  : 'uploadify.swf',
    'script'    : '/videos',
    'cancelImg' : 'images/cancel.png',
    'buttonText'  : 'Add video!',
    'folder'    : '/public',
    'auto'      : true,
    'scriptData' : {"<%= key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>" : "<%= cookies[key] %>",
        "<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>" : "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
    },
    onError : function (event, id, fileObj, errorObj) {
        alert("error: " + errorObj.info);
    }
});
```

This is my model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :source

  validates_attachment_presence :source

end
```

...and this is my migration file:

```
class CreateVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
  create_table :videos do |t|
   t.string :source_content_type
   t.string :source_file_name
   t.integer :source_file_size
   t.timestamps
 end
end

 def self.down
  drop_table :videos
 end
end
```

Now, when i upload a file, there aren't errors raised, neither client side, nor server side, but it looks like paperclip doesn't get the parameters sent him by uploadify. In fact, if i remove validation from model, resource is created without parameters.

In controller i add:

```
def create
 logger.info(params.inspect) (1)
 @video = Video.new(params[:video])
 @video.save
 logger.info @video.inspect (2)
end
```

In development.log (1) gives me

```
{"Filename"=>"prova.mov", "authenticity_token"=>"9q5w5LipGoBj Iac055OPbDofFU5FMbpEX675 RqOqs=", "folder"=>"/public", "_StreamVideo_Api_session"=>...
```

(2) without validation

```
#<Video id: 1, source_content_type: nil, source_file_name: nil, source_file_size: nil, created_at: "2011-10-10 12:12:38", updated_at: "2011-10-10 12:12:38">
```

(2) with validation

```
#<Video id: nil, source_content_type: nil, source_file_name: nil, source_file_size: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Where may be the problem?
Thank you in advance for answers!

In my view i put:

```
<h1>New video</h1>

<% form_for :video, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :source%>
<% end %>
```

But http://localhost:3000/videos/new shows me only the title!!

Answer (score 0):

the code looks ok, you should just add there `encodeURI` function. In Uploadify 2.1
it should work with:

```
 'scriptData' : {
     $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content') : encodeURI(encodeURIComponent($('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')))
  }
```

With Uploadify 3.1:

```
'formData': {
         $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content') : encodeURI($('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'))
    }
```